# How can I utilize a table and a view within a single Eloquent model based on the SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.1, I have created an Eloquent Model:

```
class Divisions extends Model
{
}
```

I have a table and a view in my database which are relevant to this model.

- `divisions_info` - The table, it will have `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries run, but will never have a `SELECT` run on it.
- `divisions_view` - The view, it will have `SELECT` queries run only (obviously).

> *The reason for the segmentation is that the `divisions_view` view joins with data from the `divisions_info` table and from another relevant, read-only table in an adjacent database.*

---

I would like to utilize one model for everything that deals with divisions, but direct any `UPDATE`/`INSERT` queries on the `divisions_info` table and all `SELECT` queries on the `divisions_view` view.

The [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage) allows you to override the assumed table name, like so:

```
protected $table = 'divisions_info';
```

However, this takes precedence over the entire model. I would like to be able to utilize all the built in methods that come with using the Eloquent model, but have it split accordingly across SQL statements.

Is this possible? If so, what is the right way to achieve it?

If it is not possible, without diving into opinion, what is the most logical/Laravel-esque way to work with the same data in two different locations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a solution:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Division extends Model {
    public function scopeFromView($query)
    {
        return $query->from('divisions_view');
    }
}
```

Just call the `fromView()` method in any part of the query like this:

```
Division::fromView()->get();
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to work very well. One thing, `from_view()` causes an exception, but removing the underscore resolves it. Thank you.

Comment: I thought the naming was working like `get*Attribute` methods, I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Cool. Also, it should be `extends Model`, not `Eloquent`. Just to make the answer solid for someone else who may stumble across this in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: You are definitely right about that. It's just a habit from Laravel 4. Updated. Thanks for the heads up!